# Get routes in javascript in the same way as in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I am working on a project in laravel, and I have the need to work the js and css files apart, and I want to see if they know a js package that will help me get the addresses as laravel does in php,

```
{{ asset ('public_assets/js/jquery.js') }}
```

Something similar in javascript,

I had found this package in github
[LaravelBA/laravel-js-routes](https://github.com/LaravelBA/laravel-js-routes)
But is already DEPRECATED
The author recommends this other package
[aaronlord/laroute](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute)
but does not have a function that does the same as laravel

**Do you know any other options?**

Comment: Why doesn't aaronlord/laroute do what you want? I have used both of those packages in the past and they provide the same functionality. Note that the example of `asset()` that you used in the question is actually a built-in part of Laravel, not a part of any add-on package.

Comment: @MosheKatz You could explain to me please detail how to do it, I'm really sorry I'm new and I'm a little lost,
I already installed the aaronlord / laroute package and put the asset function and I get the following:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: asset is not defined
  At`
could you help me please